# Android Cmake Build command failed

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, windows-10

I'm new with Cmake and ndk , when i build project i got this

```
Build command failed.


Error while executing process E:\AndroidSdkWindows\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Fehoo\Desktop\Rentie\android\butterfly-streamer -BC:\Users\Fehoo\Desktop\Rentie\android\butterfly-streamer\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Fehoo\Desktop\Rentie\android\butterfly-streamer\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Fehoo\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Fehoo\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=E:\AndroidSdkWindows\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_STL=c++_static}


 (include)   CMakeLists.txt 


-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Fehoo/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
```

note* 
I instale Cmake and ndk with location on C drive
my os is Windows 10 x64

Comment: `- Ninja` should be probably `-Ninja`

Comment: @usr1234567 the command is generated by android studio  i don't write it.

Comment: can you run `C:\Users\Fehoo\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe` from the command line?

Comment: i have this error when trying run 
{clang.exe: error: no input files}
@AlexCohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was with the directory of c++ files in **CMakeLists** file